# Why won't my apk build when I use the release flag?

Tags: cocos2d-x

If I do:

> cocos compile -p android --android-studio

My app builds without problem.

If I do:

> cocos compile -p android --android-studio -m release

I get the error:

> *** No rule to make target `/pathtomyproject/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos/editor-support/cocostudio/CCActionFrame.cpp', needed by`obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocostudio_static/CCActionFrame.o'. 
>   Stop.

Why is this happening ? I am using cocos2d-x v 3.7

EDIT: This is my Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/JNIBridge.cpp \
                   ../../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)

# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END
```

Answer (score 2):

you are seen this error because your are trying to override previous builded static library with release build , here its updating file with old one you can look your in your terminal pink highlighted text.

if you are compiling for android studio

> Goto your proj.android-studio project directory ==> than go to "app" directory
>   than remove obj directory and compile again.